# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) problem

Tags: json, google-colaboratory

i want json file open for object detection (yolo v5 or yolo v7)

so i have 51 ten thousand images and json labeling data

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTg8k.png)

but i don't solve this problem (i tried googleing but yet...)

jupyter notebook not print this problem

i think be a major cause

1. json file problem

or

2. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EClYK.png)

colab memory issue

so how i solev this problem?

please help me

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly using the open function wrongly. Now don't quote me on this but if you are trying to read data from a JSON file you would need to use the key word 'r' like so:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

'r' stands for read.